# How to make domain user for backup be part of backup operators group on one client?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

I'm using WBADMIN to backup multiple clients to a share published by some Synology NAS using SMB. That NAS is integrated in my Server 2019 AD as well as the backed up Windows clients are part of that same domain. My approach is to create one special backup user per client in the AD and configure access to the share for that user only. Afterwards I'm creating a custom task in the task scheduler of the Windows client to execute a PowerShell script wrapping execution of WBADMIN with a bit of log management, sending mails and minor stuff like that.

The important part is that the created task gets executed with the credentials of the specially created domain user for backing up this one client only. So in the end I have the users `backup_host1_wib`, `backup_host2_wib` etc. in the AD. All of those users are part of the group backup operators on the domain controller already, because they need special permissions to be executed by the task scheduler, access to the files to backup at all etc. The problem is that even though those users are contained in that group on the domain controller, task scheduler at the clients refuses to execute the task because of a lack of permissions to run the task.

What I need to do instead ist make each backup user per host additionally a member of the client-local group backup operators as well. Afterwards the task is successfully executed, WBADMIN creates the image and everything works as expected. Though, because I added those users to backup operators on the domain controller already, I had expected that this group membership communicates to the individual clients as well and I wouldn't need to assign group membership on each client manually.

So, is the behaviour by design that this special group membership doesn't publish to individual clients or am I doing something wrong? Might the group membership on the AD have simply not YET published to my test client when I tested? Though I think I even restarted it and that didn't change anything.

[image: Group membership]

**Do I really need to create a GPO instead to make each special backup user get it's expected permissions per corresponding client like described in the following article?**

Doesn't make too much sense to me, because the mentioned GPOs already contain the group backup operators and adding to that one group only seems easier to me.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/back-up-files-and-directories

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need to have a separate user for each machine?

Comment: I don't NEED strictly, it's more that I WANT, to additionally restrict access to backups by different clients if something per client goes wrong. I need client-specific dirs for various reasons on the NAS anyway, so using client-specific users with the same names as well makes a good concept. Especially because username+password need to be stored on the client for the task scheduler, Windows Backup etc. to be able to access the shares on the NAS.

Comment: Yeah - I've got an idea on that actually - it may be tedious - but it'll work.  I'll update my answer with details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - it is well known and by design that the domain's "Backup Operators" group is not the same as each machine's "Backup Operators" group.  Just as the domain's "Administrators" group or "Remote Desktop Users" group does not automatically "sync" with the correlated local groups.  They are objects with the same name existing in separate scopes.

"Backup Operators" is a built-in local group on all machines.  As Domain Controllers don't really have local groups, the BUILTIN\Backup Operators group that is in the domain is effectively the "local" Backup Operators group for all Domain Controllers.  In fact, all groups in the "BuiltIn" container are essentially the original local groups that existed on the first domain controller in the forest when it was first promoted.  The Default Value in the linked article is referring to the local groups that have the stated User Right out of the box.

I would reconsider your current approach.  What you have effectively achieved with numerous accounts in the domain's backup operators group (because of their backup privileges) is exponentially widen the attack vector against your domain and sensitive data; each of these accounts (whose passwords are now stored all over your network) have the ability to remotely connect to a domain controller, perform a backup (obtain a copy of ntds.dit for offline analysis and cracking) *and restore* your Active Directory - or possibly a corrupted or compromised copy.

I would recommend removing these accounts from the domain group immediately.

One to achieve something along the lines of what you're looking for is:

1. Create a *new* security group "local-backup-operators" or something
2. Add the backup user to this new domain group
3. Use a GPO (Restricted Groups) or GP Preference that ensures that "local-backup-operators" is a member of the local "Backup Operators" group on each machine.

---

How to more easily achieve this with a dedicated user account per-machine (my take on it).

1. Create a user for each computer you wish to backup - call it what you want but for this example on SERVER01, create a user "DOMAIN\bkp_SERVER01"
2. Create a "Local Users and Groups" Group Policy Preference Item in a
   new or existing Group Policy.
3. Action: Update; Group: Backup Operators; Members: Add - "bkp_%ComputerName% (literally, use the environment variable)
4. Profit.  Group Policy will expand the variable at runtime and search for a user/group matching that name and add the principal to the local backup operators group.

Caveat: You will get warning events generated in the logs on machines if the named account doesn't exist.  Either exclude those machines from the GPO, or just deal with the events.

Sample:

[image]

Comment: Removed my users from the AD-group and am considering using the mentioned GPO/GPP. As I still need to maintain the clients individually and manually a lot anyway, I'm simply adding the correct user to the correct client-side group only manually. Just wondered how things are expected to work, so thanks for your explanations!