# RoboCopy Access Denied, even with SeBackupPrivilege

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-permissions, robocopy

My account is a member of the Backup Operators group on the domain and I run PowerShell in elevated admin mode. I checked my privileges with `whoami /priv` and saw SeBackupPrivilege listed (disabled but nothing weird so far).

Still, when I run the command:
`robocopy 'o:\folderx' 'c:\temp' /zb`

I get an error 5 (0x0000005), "Access denied" to the source folder. Tried also using `azcopy` with the backup flag to see if it was a RoboCopy issue, and got the same "access denied" error.

I'm not the one managing the file share. Is there a way the sysadmin can deny access to accounts in the domain's "Backup Operator" group? Am I missing something in the ACL or security stuff?

I'm losing my sanity with this issue; Can anyone help look at what I'm missing?

Edit :
i finally found the solution , see my comment below

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of my error , Backup Operator is a Builtin role within the DC and is not distributed over the domain (that was the point i was missing) . for those who are as dummy as i am on Active Directory , just bear in mind that Backup Operator must be configured using a GPO to have it distributed on all the domain servers/machines (which was the point i was missing)

Comment: For better implementation of this read this QA:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1061814/how-to-make-domain-user-for-backup-be-part-of-backup-operators-group-on-one-clie